# Sorting List according to an array that contains list items Ids

Tags: c#-4.0

I have list of items, every item contains its ID and some other items. On the other hand I have an array that contains some selected item.ID

My problem is that I want to select items from item list and sort it same as the array sorting using Linq

NOTE: array not sorted ascending or descending.

```
usedCountriesIds = TransporPlan.OrderBy(tr => tr.TripOrder).Select(t => t.CountyID).ToArray();

List tripCountries = LeafCountries.Where(c => usedCountriesIds.Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
```

I need to order tripCountries list according to usedCountriesIds array

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: As well as clarifying your question you need to post some relevant code.

Comment: the list contain list of countries ... Ids array contain countries ids sorted accordint to TripOrder 
i want to show the user the destinations that the trip will visit sorted according to TripOrder

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate your list of countries from the IDs:

```
IEnumerable<Country> tripCountries = 
    usedCountriesIds.Select(uc => LeafCountries.Single(lc => lc.ID == uc));
```

Comment: @HaidarHaidar Great. Please click the tick to accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.